# Why does the "LaTeX" logo have random capitalisation and letter height?

Tags: syntax, logos

Why does LaTex have random capitalisation and letter height?

**Context:**

So I'm sure this is a rather random question which probably has a really obvious answer, but since I couldn't find it on this site I've decided that I might as well ask it to quench my curiosity:

**Question**

I often see the LaTeX logo written like the following image:

[image: LaTex]

And I've always wondered why this is so? I've also seen it on this site as LaTeX.

So:

- Why does this site have a capital T and X? Does "TeX" represent something?
- Why do other sites have a raised A and lowered E? Does that represent anything?

**Post - Note**

Again, apologies if this is an obvious question and has already been asked. If so, please don't downvote, just give me the link to where it has been asked or tell me the answer. Also, I wasn't really sure what to tag this question - "syntax"?

Comment: There's nothing *random* about the raising of the letter "A" in the "LaTeX" logo or the lowering of the letter "E" in the "TeX" logo. The creator of TeX, Donald Knuth, came up with the logo that may be produced by running `\TeX`. Leslie Lamport (the creator of a set of TeX macros which he called "LaTeX", short for "Lamport's TeX") created the logo which may be produced by typing `\LaTeX`. The question as to *why* Knuth and Lamport chose to create these particular logos can only be answered with "Well, the designers were expressing their creativity".

Comment: I see! Good to know. You might want to put that as an answer @Mico? Or I can answer my question if you don't have time (from past experience I think you are quite busy answering questions).

Comment: Please go ahead and post an answer of your own. Please be sure to also provide a link to [David Carlisle's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118046/5001) to the query [(La)TeX Logo - Where does it come from?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118043/5001)

Comment: Does these answer your question ? [What is the meaning of moved letters on LaTeX logo?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95253/138900) and [(La)TeX Logo - Where does it come from?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118043/138900) There is also the fact that the TEX logo (with no letter offset) belonged to IBM.

Comment: Ah it does @AndréC but I see not much point in closing this now that Mico has invested time into answering it. If you still wish to close it, tell me and I can delete the question, though I'm not sure how that helps the community and rewards Mico for answering the question

Comment: @Gil I did not ask for closure on this issue.

Comment: Ok thanks @AndréC.

Comment: @Gill Closing a question is not the same as deleting the question, nor does it take away “rewards” from anyone who has answered it. (In any case, Mico has not “answered” this question in the Stack Exchange sense; he has only left a comment: only you have (self-)answered it.) A closed question remains forever (unless deleted), and remains searchable; all that closing a question does is prevent more people from adding answers to *that* question, and (when the question is closed as a duplicate) it serves as a notice that an earlier question exist elsewhere, possibly with more or better answers.

Comment: @AndréC -- Actually, "TEX" was owned by Honeywell.  This is documented in chapter 1 of the *TeXbook*.  It was a gentlemen's agreement that TeX for the composition software should forever be identified with a lowered "e", which in ordinary text (where the logo can't be realized) is "TeX".

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you for that clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, because I think @Mico is very busy answering other questions, I'll quote his comments as a separate answer to [this posting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118046/5001)):

> There's nothing *random* about the raising of the letter "A" in the "LaTeX" logo or the lowering of the letter "E" in the "TeX" logo.

> The creator of TeX, Donald Knuth, came up with the logo that may be produced by running `\TeX`. Leslie Lamport (the creator of a set of TeX macros which he called "LaTeX", possibly short for "Lamport's TeX") created the logo which may be produced by typing `\LaTeX`.

> The question as to *why* Knuth and Lamport chose to create these particular logos can only be answered with "Well, the designers were expressing their creativity".

Well, consider my curiosity quenched... **Thanks to Mico once more!**